# fullcalendarjs vertical resource view shows only the last event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

fullcalendarjs vertical resource view shows only the last event.

i am using the react version with vertical resources, i have purchased a license, could somebody help me out?

```
    <FullCalendar
eventsSet={this.handleEvents}
timeZone={'Europe/Amsterdam'}
plugins={[momentPlugin, resourceTimeGridPlugin]}
dateClick={this.contextMenu}
select={this.test}
initialView='resourceTimeGridDay'
editable={true}
selectable={true}
selectMirror={false}
dayMaxEvents={true}// custom render function
allDaySlot={false}
axisFormat={'HH:mm'}
selectOverlap={true}
selectHelper={true}
timeFormat={'HH:mm'}
slotLabelFormat={'HH:mm'}
slotDuration={'0:15'}
snapDuration={'0:15'}
windowResizeDelay={0}
eventLongPressDelay={0}
longPressDelay={0}
minTime={'00:00:00'}
maxTime={'24:00:00'}
locale={nlLocale}
headerToolbar={false}
events={this.state.events}
schedulerLicenseKey={''}
resources={this.state.resources}
ref={this.calendarComponentRef}
displayEventEnd={true}
/>
```

thnx in advance

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved, the problem was the handleEvents function,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't help anyone who might have a similar problem. You need to make your answer more specific and share the code changes you made in order for it to work